# Why would someone using Core Data want to use more than one persistent store in the same Managed Object Model?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm pretty new to Core Data, and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might have cases where you want different types of data stored in different places or with different behaviors. For example you might have one read only sqlite store shipped as part of your app containing some default data, an additional store for updates to that data set you have downloaded from a server, and a third for user data. Alternately you might have a case where you want some objects to be persisted while others can live in an in-memory store and do not need to be saved between uses of the app.

Comment: Migrating data can be a PITA so perhaps if you have volatile data schema it's worth segmenting out.  I hadn't really thought about these things, good question and good answer +1

Comment: It sounds like the use-case you described in your first example implies the server is sending a Core Data compliant persistent store. Otherwise (unless I'm misunderstanding anything) you could simply import your data into the same store you use for everything else (barring read-only data).

Comment: @Joshua Pokotilow, true you could have just a read-only store and a single editable store for user and app data if that makes sense for your application. It depends on how you want to organize them and if you want them stored in different locations. For example you might want to back up user data but can store updates to app data in the caches directory since you can redownload that if necessary. Similarly user data might need to be encrypted while app configuration data might not.